# getting wrong format of date in Django

Tags: python, html, django, datetime, web-development-server

I am trying to create a form to receive date input from the user and then pass that input to my another python script my Django form code is as below

```
from Django import forms


class NameForm(forms.Form):
    lev=forms.IntegerField(label='lev')
    status = forms.CharField(label='status', max_length=100)
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%Y/%m/%d',attrs={'type': 'date'}))
```

i am receiving the date and all other values in my views.py file and then passing them to my python script my views.py code is

```
def generate(request):
    form=NameForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        a=str(form.cleaned_data.get('lev'))
        b= form.cleaned_data.get('status')
        c=str(form.cleaned_data.get('start_date'))
       


    output=run([sys.executable,'C:\\Users\\siddhant\\Desktop\\internship\\indicator\\work\\water.py',a,b,c],stdout=PIPE,text=True)
    

    events_list=level.objects.all()
    return render(request,'result.html',{'res':events_list})
```

and I am doing a strptime conversion of passed date in my work.py code as follow

```
current_level=int(sys.argv[1])
x=sys.argv[2]
start_date=sys.argv[3]
print(start_date)
start=datetime.strptime(start_date, "%y/%d/%m")
```

but i am getting error  that ValueError: time data '2022-01-01' does not match format '%y/%d/%m'
please can someone suggest how to do tackle with this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the `date` object properly when calling the function:

```
def generate(request):
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        a = str(form.cleaned_data['lev'])
        b = form.cleaned_data.get('status')
        c = form.cleaned_data.get('start_date').strftime('%y/%d/%M')
        output=run([sys.executable,'C:\\Users\\siddhant\\Desktop\\internship\\indicator\\work\\water.py',a,b,c],stdout=PIPE,text=True)
```

In the `water.py` program, you should parse it with `%M`, not `%m`, otherwise you are parsing the *minute*, not the *month*:

```
current_level = int(sys.argv[1])
x = sys.argv[2]
start_date = sys.argv[3]
print(start_date)
start = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%y/%d/%M")
```

Comment: I tried it it didn't work the problem is my input date  format is '2022-01-01' but at strptime to change this string to datetime object  , "%y/%d/%M" I am going this that's why showing error i want to change the input date format from '2022-01-01'  to '2022/01/01'

Comment: @SiddhantsinghBhadauria: that's because `form.cleaned_data.get('start_date')` is a `date` object, and the `str(..)` of a `date` object is always `yyyy-mm-dd`. That's why you should use the `strftime`.